# Android font ttf or otf typeface rendering random symblols/letters

Tags: android, fonts, android-custom-view, text-rendering, android-typeface

I have a custom `View` in which I am drawing some text. I am using various free otf/ttf font files which are available in the assets folder

```
public class ProjectView extends View {
    private final Paint textPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    private void init(Context context) {
        textPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts" + File.separator + fontFileName);
        textPaint.setTypeface(typeface);
    }
}
```

Everything seems to be working fine except one thing: The words I am drawing get randomly messed up, meaning the letters are randomly replaced with other letters or symbols.

Here is an example:

[image]

The correct word is in the left image but sometimes it gets drawn like in the right image. Calling `invalidate()` again everything gets rendered correctly again fixes the problem.

This effect is more obvious in a `ListView`, it happens more often there because of the frequent redraws as I call `notifyDatasetChanged()` on each item click. In the adapter I use it like this:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_fonts, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtFont = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtFont);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        //tried this two but no success
        holder.txtFont.setPaintFlags(holder.txtFont.getPaintFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG | Paint.DEV_KERN_TEXT_FLAG);
        holder.txtFont.getPaint().setSubpixelText(true);

        holder.txtFont.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, fonts.get(position).getSize());

        holder.txtFont.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts" + File.separator + font.getFileName()));
}
```

To be honest, I have no idea what causes this or how I could prevent it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you tell us which fonts you are using? Especially those that cause problems might be important.

Comment: This happens randomly on all fonts I am using. The ttf files are from Google Fonts.

Comment: Can you please post a link to at least one font you are having a problem with? I want to try and reproduce the problem.

Comment: This for instance: https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Acme

Comment: i'd suggest that you hold the font as a static variable or something, and load it only once.

Comment: Ok I cannot reproduce the problem. Most likely it has nothing to do with the fonts.

Comment: I tested it with this font: [**Link**](http://fontpro.com/download-family.php?file=35256).

Comment: Are you sure it is a font problem? Maybe the problem lies with the `Strings` you want to display.

Comment: Try to use the font I link to above and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Just to make sure, does this happen only with your custom view, or also with standard widgets?

Comment: Is there any way you could post a sample project reproducing this issue?

Comment: Thank you  Xaver Kapeller for taking your time with my question. As in the answer bellow, it seems that if I cache the TypeFaces, the problem is solved (or at least it should happen more rarely).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating the typeface every time getView is called. This is inefficient, and could cause races while loading and parsing the typeface files.

Instead have in the activity a map of all loaded typefaces, and load each one only once.

I would even try to manage the typefaces on the Application class, if many activities and views use the same typefaces.

Comment: While this is a good suggestion, I don't really see how it could be related to the problem. Isn't `Typeface.createFromAsset()` synchronous? And these calls are all from the UI thread. Why would it create a race condition?

Comment: Having typeface created for each font (I am using around 100 font files) seems to make this happen way less often, almost cannot see it again, so definitely an improvement. The thing is, having all these 100 Typeface objects won't use too much memory? The user might never scroll through the whole list. Indeed, I was creating typefaces on getView

Comment: @Alin In a similar app (with about 50 fonts), I did not see a significant memory use when loading all fonts. If the font file is small, the memory it takes should be small too. You can also cache only the fonts that are actually used upon first use.

Comment: @matiash Loading a font file requires reading a file, parsing it and creating memory data structures for it. I assume some of the work is done in another thread, probably a native thread. Not 100% sure as I did not look at the Android code.

Comment: @yoah how about this: I creat the Typeface on getView BUT I also store it in cache, so next time the item is loaded, I simply take the typeface from there ?

Comment: Works like a charm, I'll leave it like this for now. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

May be this might help somebody. I got the same problem. I solved it using `lru` cache.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.MetricAffectingSpan;
import android.util.LruCache;

public class TypefaceSpan extends MetricAffectingSpan {
    private static LruCache<String, Typeface> sTypefaceCache = new LruCache<>(12);
    private Typeface mTypeface;

    public TypefaceSpan(Context context, String typefaceName) {
        mTypeface = sTypefaceCache.get(typefaceName);

        if (mTypeface == null) {
            mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getApplicationContext().getAssets(),
                    String.format("fonts/%s", typefaceName));
            sTypefaceCache.put(typefaceName, mTypeface);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint p) {
        p.setTypeface(mTypeface);
        p.setFlags(p.getFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
        tp.setTypeface(mTypeface);
        tp.setFlags(tp.getFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
    }
}
```

example:

```
private TypefaceSpan typefaceSpan;
```

constructor:

```
typefaceSpan = new TypefaceSpan(context, "name_of_font.otf");
```

getView:

```
typefaceSpan.updateDrawState(holder.title.getPaint());
```